# Increase efficiency of for loop with conditional logic

Tags: r, loops

I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do this but I haven't found it. The code below takes more than 2.5 hours of CPU time to process a little more than a million records.

Sample input data:

```
PATIENTID,admit_dt,discharge_dt,days_since_last_discharge,window_end_dt
55,35684,35688,NA,0
55,35693,35697,5,0
55,35719,35724,22,0
55,35738,35745,14,0
55,35758,35763,13,0
55,35798,35808,35,0
55,35817,35831,9,0
1564,31322,31339,NA,0
1564,31342,31350,3,0
1564,31353,31370,3,0
1564,31373,31438,3,0
1564,31439,31456,1,0
1564,31477,31480,NA,0
1564,31486,31489,6,0
1564,31499,31506,10,0
1564,31512,31522,6,0
1564,31525,31545,NA,0
1564,31547,31559,2,0
1564,31563,31568,4,0
1564,31606,31630,38,0
1564,31643,31653,13,0
1564,31656,31669,3,0
1564,31670,31680,1,0
1564,31685,31701,5,0
1564,31710,31713,9,0
1564,31724,31725,11,0
1564,31726,31733,1,0
1564,31753,31762,20,0
1564,31769,31770,7,0
1564,31807,31824,37,0
1564,31828,31831,4,0
1564,31981,31989,150,0
1564,32003,32008,14,0
```

Approaches that I've tried and work but are slow:

```
window_size <- 30
last_window_dt <- 0
for (row in 1:nrow(sample_df)) {
    if(is.na(sample_df[row, "days_since_last_discharge"])) {
        sample_df[row, "window_end_dt"] <- sample_df[row, "discharge_dt"] + window_size
        last_window_dt <- sample_df[row, "discharge_dt"] + window_size
    }
    else {if (sample_df[row, "admit_dt"] <= last_window_dt) {
            sample_df[row, "window_end_dt"] <- last_window_dt
        } else {
            sample_df[row, "window_end_dt"] <- sample_df[row, "discharge_dt"] + window_size
            last_window_dt <- sample_df[row, "discharge_dt"] + window_size
        }
    }
}
```

alternative that actually takes longer to execute:

```
window_size <- 30
last_window_dt <- 0
for (row in 1:nrow(sample_df)) {
ifelse(is.na(sample_df[row, "days_since_last_discharge"]) | sample_df[row, "admit_dt"] >     last_window_dt,
        last_window_dt <- sample_df[row, "discharge_dt"] + window_size,
        last_window_dt
        )
ifelse(is.na(sample_df[row, "days_since_last_discharge"]) | sample_df[row, "admit_dt"] >     last_window_dt,
        sample_df[row, "window_end_dt"] <- sample_df[row, "discharge_dt"] + window_size,
        sample_df[row, "window_end_dt"] <- last_window_dt
        )
}
```

desired output:

```
PATIENTID,admit_dt,discharge_dt,days_since_last_discharge,window_end_dt
55,35684,35688,NA,35718
55,35693,35697,5,35718
55,35719,35724,22,35754
55,35738,35745,14,35754
55,35758,35763,13,35793
55,35798,35808,35,35838
55,35817,35831,9,35838
1564,31322,31339,NA,31369
1564,31342,31350,3,31369
1564,31353,31370,3,31369
1564,31373,31438,3,31468
1564,31439,31456,1,31468
1564,31477,31480,NA,31510
1564,31486,31489,6,31510
1564,31499,31506,10,31510
1564,31512,31522,6,31552
1564,31525,31545,NA,31575
1564,31547,31559,2,31575
1564,31563,31568,4,31575
1564,31606,31630,38,31660
1564,31643,31653,13,31660
1564,31656,31669,3,31660
1564,31670,31680,1,31710
1564,31685,31701,5,31710
1564,31710,31713,9,31710
1564,31724,31725,11,31755
1564,31726,31733,1,31755
1564,31753,31762,20,31755
1564,31769,31770,7,31800
1564,31807,31824,37,31854
1564,31828,31831,4,31854
1564,31981,31989,150,32019
1564,32003,32008,14,32019
```

Comment: what's the logic you're using to calculate `window_end_dt` ?

Comment: What is window_size?

Comment: Edited the code - added definition for window_size.

Answer (score 0):

Dropping the for loop altogether and parallelising some stuff will probably help.

For example, rather than looping through each row to find NAs, you can just use...

```
naMatches <- is.na(sample_df[, "days_since_last_discharge"])
```

Which will give us an index for where all the NAs are. So we can then complete the next operation in parallel.

```
sample_df[naMatches, "window_end_dt"] <- sample_df[naMatches, "discharge_dt"] + window_size
```

After that the main trick seems to be working out how to complete `last_window_dt` in parallel. It sounds like you just want to to a few matrix operations on repeat enough times. Perhaps something like the below process would work?

```
#Fill all the NA values with our first guess of window_end_dt, which is just what the NAs are.
sample_df$window_end_dt <- zoo::na.locf(sample_df$window_end_dt)

#Give the value of the window_end_dt prior to all those where admit_dt is less
sample_df$window_end_dt[sample_df$admit_dt <= sample_df$window_end_dt] <- dplyr::lead(sample_df$window_end_dt, 1)[sample_df$admit_dt <= sample_df$window_end_dt]

#Give the value of discharge_dt to all those where admit_dt is greater
sample_df$window_end_dt[sample_df$admit_dt > sample_df$window_end_dt] <- sample_df$discharge_dt[sample_df$admit_dt > sample_df$window_end_dt] + window_size
```

I haven't put too much thought into that, but if you changed your process such that you were doing full frame checks, you could just look through those until you found the values in your `window_end_dt` column didn't change anymore. This would be useless though if you ended up needing to loop through this more times than the number of rows you have.

In summary, my answer is that for `window_end_dt`, so long as the process depend son previous values, i.e. each following row is dependent on the last in some dynamic way, we'll probably need some form of looping, at which point the process needs to change to make it work.

Others might have cleverer answers, but if not, don't take the section of code I wrote as an absolute, it may not function 100 as you require, but hopefully this is a good starting point for you to try and come up with a faster method.

Comment: I've been experimenting with your suggestions as time permits. The plyr::lag(sample_df$window_end_dt, -1) doesn't work for me - plyr doesn't have a lag function (maybe it used to?). dplyr has a lag function but won't take a negative number to lag by.

Comment: Ah, my apologies! I should have typed `dplyr` instead of `plyr`. Also you're correct, I shouldn't have used `lag` with a negative value, I should of used `lead` which is just the inverse of that :) I also realised that I wasn't restricting the range of the lead in my example. But essentially we just wanted to shift the value by 1 to grab the thing before it, then still just take the ones we're interested in. Keep me updated on how the experimenting goes!